# Initializing struct member with type DWORD64

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct, 64-bit

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, write in C++ and compile binary for x64 platform. In my project I have useful structure for memory blocks with data pointer and size:

```
typedef struct _MEMORY_BLOCK
{
    DWORD64 Length;
    LPBYTE  lpData;
}
MEMORY_BLOCK, *LPMEMORY_BLOCK;
```

In other file I have key definition:

```
BYTE PublicKey[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, ... };
DWORD64 PublicKeyLength = (DWORD64)sizeof(PublicKey);
MEMORY_BLOCK ServerKey = { PublicKeyLength, PublicKey };
```

On x86 platform structure initialization of ServerKey works fine, but on x64 platform it results in MEMORY_BLOCK struct filled with zeroes. If I change members order in structure (e.g. lpData at first, and second is Length), lpData initializes properly, but Length is still equal to zero.

Now I have workaround with function that sets ServerKey values in runtime, but I need to know why I could not initialize DWORD64 struct member in ServerKey definition.

Comment: 1. Pick a language. 2. In lieu of not being told/shown in your partial sample code, and being given no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we are left to *guess* the storage lifetime of all of the above, which leads to 3. Assuming *static* lifetime of at least *one* element, what of the results after removing at-least one of those layers and just using, say  `{ sizeof(PublicKey), PublicKey }`.

Comment: sizeof(PublicKey) works, but I'm still interested if it is a bug. I can initialize pointer variable by another pointer variable, but cannot initialize 64-bit integer in structure by variable of same type?

Comment: P. S. I code in Pure C, no classes, no namespaces. Variable PublicKey is global.

Comment: Why did you say you wrote in C++ then? Different languages, different semantics.

Comment: It should be simple to provide an MCVE. Then we don't need to do the work, guessing as we go.